# jQuery does not see my dynamically loaded checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, post

I have written a script that will load a series of products into a div tag.

I now want to be able to filter those products using a series of checkboxes.

jquery makes a $post to an ASP page that returns an XML dataset.  The first element of the data set contains a list of manufacturers in this format ara|dai|sid|alp etc.  The second element contains the manufacturer names of the codes above.

I then use this script to build a list of checkboxes into a div tag.

```
var mc = new Array();
mc = $("manCodes",xml).text().split(",");
var manTitles = new Array();
manTitles = $("manTitles",xml).text().split(",");

for ( var i=0, len=mc.length; i<len; ++i ){
    m += '<span><input type="checkbox" value="' + mc[i] + '" name="man[]" id="man_'+i+'" />' + manTitles[i] +'</span>'//mc[i];
    }
manufacturers = '<div id="filter" class="man">FILTER<br />' + m + '</div>';
$(".formSelect").append(manufacturers);
```

This works a treat and then in the Document Ready section I have a code segment that looks for any click on a checkbox:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
     $("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    loadXML($("#sortOrder option:selected").val(),$("#limitBy option:selected").val(),$("#productGroup").val());
     });
});
```

This is where my code falls over because any click on any checkbox is not working.  Its almost like JQuery cannot see these checkboxes that it has created.

Can anybody please help how to resolve this problem please?

Cheers
Graham

Comment: Use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)...

Answer (score 1):

You need event delegation, otherwise the event handler will not fire for dynamically inserted/removed elements. [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) are two options.

```
$("input:checkbox").live("click", function() {
    // implementation
});
```

or better:

```
$("form").delegate("input:checkbox", "click", function() {
    // implementation
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to capture events from dynamically added elements.

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

```
 $("input:checkbox").live("click", function() {
     loadXML($("#sortOrder option:selected").val(),$("#limitBy option:selected").val(),$("#productGroup").val());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
     $("input:checkbox").live("click",function() {
    loadXML($("#sortOrder option:selected").val(),$("#limitBy   option:selected").val(),$("#productGroup").val());
     });
});
```

Comment: That was amazingly quick, thank you so much.  It worked a treat, would you mind explaining what this does?

Comment: When you call click it will bind the event to whatever checkbox are present at the moment in the DOM. This event binding happens before you create new checkbox and hence those new checkboxes are not attached the event listener. The live method works for those elements (in this case checkboxes) which gets added later, thats why it is named "live"